# Does my D-Link DWR 921 router use both antennas for an LTE connection?

Tags: router, antenna

I just purchased a D-Link DWR 921 router, which has a slot for a SIM card.

This is related to the internet speed/LTE reception, not the wireless (wifi).

It has two detachable antennas, and I discovered that if I leave the right antenna, it has almost the same speed (via an internet speedtest) as with both antennas;

Also, if leave only the left antenna, the speed is really slow, and the upload is almost 0Kb.

Is this a matter of firmware (no luck there, I just upgraded to the latest), is it faulty, or is it really only needing one antenna, and why?

Comment: jackJoe, Did you ever figure this out? I am purchasing this router and have an external mounted antenna. Just 1. I am wondering if it is required to have 2 external mounted antennas or if I am able to utilize just one of the routers antenna ports.

Comment: @AdamJosephLooze D-Link replied saying it was normal (just one antenna). I returned my D-Link and bought a TP-LInk TL-MR6400, very good! much better software/control compared to the D-Link, also allows external antennas, I recommend TP-Link over the D-Link for this type of router.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the picture on this page: https://openwrt.org/toh/d-link/d-link_dwr-921
Both antennas as clearly connected to the LTE modem.

Answer (score 0):

> It has two detachable antennas, and I discovered that if I leave the
>   right antenna, it has almost the same speed (via an internet
>   speedtest) as with both antennas;
>
> Also, if leave only the left antenna, the speed is really slow, and
>   the upload is almost 0Kb.

NB: The LTE antenna depends on the revision of your router. I would accept user2480144's answer, because he links to a reputable source which lists the different revisions and photos of the connectivity.

> Is this a matter of firmware (no luck there, I just upgraded to the
>   latest), is it faulty, or is it really only needing one antenna, and
>   why?

No the antenna depends on your revision. You should be able to see the revision of your router in the ui. See user2480144's answer!!!

Note that if you install OpenWRT, open the router up and plug in a 5G card, when these become available, you will get 5G! That is what I will do ...